# Iterating over founded objects with indexes

Tags: jquery

I get an error : `obj.attr is not a function`.

```
  clone.find(".blockBase").each(function(i, obj) {
     obj.attr("id",newid+"b"+i);
     console.log("Base",i);
  });
```

I can't figure out why ? `obj` should be a `jquery` element.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(obj)` or debugging it to see what exactly is `obj`?

Comment: use `$(obj).attr`

Comment: @epascarello thanks, why can't i use obj ?

Comment: Also, there is really no need to access the `obj` argument: using `$(this).attr()` should do the job.

Comment: because the method returns the DOM, not jquery

Comment: thanks very much! so basic. sorry.

Comment: `obj.id = newid +'b'+ i` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/each/
The second parameter (in your case `obj`) as well as the context (`this`) for the `.each()` function is a DOM element, NOT a jquery object.
Use `$(obj).attr()` as commented above.
Thus you will construct a jquery object with this DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

The each method returns the dom object, not a jquery object, so to use attr() you need to convert it to a jQuery object.

```
$(obj).attr("id",newid + "b" + i);
```

If you are just changing the id, I would use attr with a function.

```js
const clone = $("ul")
const newid = "foo"
clone.find(".blockBase").attr("id", function (i) {
  return newid + "b" + i;
})
```

```css
li::after {
  content: attr(id);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="blockBase">1</li>
  <li class="blockBase">2</li>
  <li class="blockBase">3</li>
  <li class="blockBase">4</li>
  <li class="blockBase">5</li>
</ul>
```